# Create Thread in a new window c++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, console

How can I create some new Threads and run this threads in a new console windows ??

Comment: What is your platform?  Operating system?  Compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You get one console window per Win32 process, so to get a true "console" you will have to spawn separate processes for each of these subtasks.

Or, you can write your own GUI which acts like a console but isn't actually a "Win32 Console".  If the console is output-only, then a readonly text-box with fixed-width font works pretty well.

Comment: Also think so. But my task sounds like my question.
I just want to know that there is no another ways to create Thread in a new window, avoiding creation of a new Process.

Comment: @bada I also think you can't do this. You have to spawn separate process for another console window. Please read AllocConsole documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @baga: The new thread can certainly create a new window, but it won't be a Win32 console window.